# Write a csv file from a dictionary with compound keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose keys are tuples of 2 items. I would like to write this dictionary as a `.csv` file.

My dictionary `counter` looks like this :

```
{("Banana", "Apple") : 1,
 ("Apple", "Pear") : 2,
 # ...
}
```

I've tried this:

```
header = ['group', 'list', 'id']
with open("file.csv", 'w') as f2:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f2, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    for key, val in counter.items(): 
        write.writerow([key]+val)
```

But I get this error:

`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

Can somebody help me?

#### Edit

I've tried with this, too:

```
with open("file.csv", 'w+') as f2:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f2, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    for key, val in counter.items():
        writer.writerow(key,val)
```

But it now says:

`TypeError: writerow() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Where is `counter` coming from and what is it?

Comment: sorry, counter is my dictionnary, should have mention it

Comment: That helps. Please show what in this dictionary (or at least a sample of it, if it's huge), because that will make it possible to answer your question.

Comment: It's like this : { "Banana", "Pear" : 1 etc....} I have this kind of key from the dictionnary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample of the contents of the `counter` dictionary you added, I now understand what you're trying to do.

Here's how to accomplish what you want:

```
import csv

counter = {("Banana", "Apple"): 1,
           ("Apple", "Pear"): 2,
           # ...
          }

header = 'group', 'list', 'id'
with open("compound_keys.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    for (group, list_), id in counter.items():
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(header, (group, list_, id))))
```

Contents of `.csv` file created:

```
group,list,id
Banana,Apple,1
Apple,Pear,2
```

**Note**

It would be simpler and more efficient in this case to use a [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) instead of a `csv.DictWriter` because then it wouldn't be nesssary to create a temporary dictionary to write each row of the output file (only a tuple).

The following produces exactly the same results:

```
header = 'group', 'list', 'id'
with open("compound_keys.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for (group, list_), id in counter.items():
        writer.writerow((group, list_, id))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the plain `with open`:

```
with open("file.csv", 'a+') as f:
    f.write('group' + ',' + 'list' + ',' + 'id'
    for key, value in f2.items():
        f.write(key[0] + ',' + key[1] + ',' + str(value))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't make the result I want....

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau), we can't really help without knowing what `counter` is, however, I think I see what's going wrong.

What you're saying is not possible. Every dictionary has an equal amount of keys as values, a key can't exist without a value.

From your question, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
header = ['group', 'list', 'id']
with open('file.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    keys = list(counter.keys())
    values = list(counter.items())
    writer.writerow([keys[0], keys[1], values[0]])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I get this error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys' for this line  writer.writerow([keys[0], keys[1], values[0]])